# How to load very big timeseries file(s) in Python to do analysis?

Tags: python, csv, time-series

I have some .gz files and they contain data on some timeseries. Naturally, I would like to do some timeseries analysis on this.

I tried this:

```
import gzip
f=gzip.open('data.csv.gz','r')
file_content=f.read()
print(file_content)
```

But it was loading for 20mins and I manually stopped it.

My question is, how should I read this? I have some ideas on using Dask, Spark, or should I just yield the lines?

Tried looking in the internet industry standards.

Comment: How big is very big?

Comment: between 5 to 20GB

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use Dask as follows:

   ```
   import dask.dataframe as dd

   df = dd.read_csv('data.csv.gz', compression='gzip')
   ```
2. Apache spark also supports reading .gz files. (It might be overkill
   for small datasets.
3. Yielding lines: If you’re writing a function to process the file, you can use a generator to yield lines one by one. This is memory-efficient as only one line is loaded into memory at a time.

Comment: thanks for the reply! Is there any "favourite" for time series analysis?

Comment: @fernandoVictoriaValpuesta It varies based on the specific use case and the technology stack of the organization. However, gzip , Dask and Spark are all commonly used tools.